# How can I force Mailgun to send an e-mail using base64 encoding via API (php)?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, mailgun

I am sending an HTML e-mail via API whichi s UTF-8, however Mailgun seems to sometime use base64/UTF-8 and sometimes use quoted-printable ascii.

I am having a problem with Outlook 2013 (incorrectly I believe) re-writing the header of the HTML e-mail from UTF-8 to ascii and then not displaying my pound sign: £ as it doesn't exist in ascii.

I suspect this is happening in Outlook 2013 becuase the character encoding of the mime part is ascii and the e-mail is UTF-8. I believe the only way to get round this is to force Mailgun to send the e-mail using base64 mime encoding and UTF-8 but I don't know how to force that to happen using the API.

Answer (score 2):

I am quite sure this is not the best solution but in case it helps anyone, I have simply added a pound sign which is styled white. I know it seems horrible, but I haven't found anything better and it seems to work!

```
<font style="font-size: 2px;" color="#ffffff" size="2">£</font>
```

Comment: did you manage to find a more general solution to this? :) Blast from the past!

Comment: Sadly no - still doing it that way. (also still embarrassed about the solution!)